# Scoreboard object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am making a scoreboard for a game and need to write two functions to be able to add points and subtract points from it.

This is what my **scoreboard.js** file looks like:

```
var ScoreBoard = function (currentScore) {
  this.currentScore = currentScore;
  console.log('ScoreBoard created');
};

ScoreBoard.prototype.addPoint = function() {
  console.log(this.currentScore + 1);
};
```

I create a new instance of `ScoreBoard` in my **index.html** and add an add function, but I can't get the current score to update when I call this in console, I just get `1`.

```
scoreBoard.addPoint();
```

This is what is in my index:

```
var scoreBoard = new ScoreBoard(0);
var addFunction = scoreBoard.addPoint;
```

How can I make the current score update when a point is added or deducted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log(this.currentScore + 1);` doesn't actually increment `this.currentScore`.

What you've written is in effect `x + 1`, when you should have written `x = x + 1`.

Comment: Thank you that was the problem!